# How can you "parameterize" Clojure Contrib's test-is?

Tags: testing, clojure, clojure-contrib, test-is

Both [Junit](http://www.junit.org/) and [TestNG](http://testng.org/doc/index.html) provide mechanisms for iterating over a collection of input parameters and running your tests against them. In Junit this is supported via the [Parameterized annotation](http://isagoksu.com/2009/development/agile-development/test-driven-development/using-junit-parameterized-annotation/), while TestNG uses **@DataProvider**.

How can you write data-driven tests using the **test-is** library? I tried using **for** list comprehension to iterate over an input parameter collection, but because **deftest** is a macro it's expecting **is** clauses.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From reading the article on parameterized tests in Junit it seems that once you get past the poiler plate the cool part of parameterization is that it lets you type this:

```
      return Arrays.asList(new Object[][] {
            { 2, true },
            { 6, false },
            { 19, true },
            { 22, false }
```

and easily define four tests.

in test-is the equivalent (no boiler-plate code required) macro is `are`

```
(are [n prime?] (= prime? (is-prime n))  
     3 true
     8 false)
```

If you want to give your inputs as a map then you could run something like:

```
(dorun (map #(is (= %2 (is-prime %1)) 
            { 3 true, 8 false}))
```

though the `are` macro will produce more easily read output.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure I understand the point of parameterized tests, but I would use dynamic binding for this.

```
user> (def *test-data* [0 1 2 3 4 5])
#'user/*test-data*

user> (deftest foo
        (doseq [x *test-data*]
           (is (< x 4))))
#'user/foo
user> (run-tests)

Testing user

FAIL in (foo) (NO_SOURCE_FILE:1)
expected: (< x 4)
  actual: (not (< 4 4))

FAIL in (foo) (NO_SOURCE_FILE:1)
expected: (< x 4)
  actual: (not (< 5 4))

Ran 1 tests containing 6 assertions.
2 failures, 0 errors.
nil

user> (defn run-tests-with-data [data]
        (binding [*test-data* data] (run-tests)))
#'user/run-tests-with-data

user> (run-tests-with-data [0 1 2 3])

Testing user

Ran 1 tests containing 4 assertions.
0 failures, 0 errors.
nil
```

You could rewrite `deftest` and `run-tests` yourself.  It'd be maybe a dozen lines of Clojure to let tests accept parameters in some other way.